# Redirecting to login form after successful login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got a Spring MVC web (v5.1.2) and I've been developing a REST API with Basic Authentication. Now I need some pages with forms tu upload big files and I want a login form to access to those pages.

I'm using Spring's default login form and I've configured my app with this config file:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("login.html","**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            //.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().realmName(CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("login*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home.html",true).failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")/*.loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/hello.html",true).failureForwardUrl("/login.html")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")*/;
}

@Bean
public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint(){
    return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
}
```

}

If I do a failure login I see Bad Credentials message and the url with the query param, and with a correct login I see in the Chrome console that it goes to home.html but with a 302 redirects goes to /login again. So... After a successful login it asks for login again.

Where is my mistake??

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here my DEBUG logs:

```
(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:87) - Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@140bfb00

(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:312) - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d823b1ed: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@677d9ddb: Username: bar@foo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: B2A4A0CE1260CE33BB9663E7C4F4D0A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN

(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:54) - Redirecting to '/home.html'

(HstsHeaderWriter.java:129) - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@682780f8

(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:380) - SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d823b1ed: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d823b1ed: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@677d9ddb: Username: bar@foo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: B2A4A0CE1260CE33BB9663E7C4F4D0A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2b36c88f

(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:119) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'

(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:210) - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d823b1ed: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d823b1ed: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@677d9ddb: Username: bar@foo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: B2A4A0CE1260CE33BB9663E7C4F4D0A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:176) - Checking match of request : '/home.html'; against '/logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /home.html' doesn't match 'POST /logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /home.html' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /home.html' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:72) - No matches found

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /home.html' doesn't match 'POST /login'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter'

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:176) - Checking match of request : '/home.html'; against '/logout'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'

(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:95) - saved request doesn't match

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'

(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:106) - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d823b1ed: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@677d9ddb: Username: bar@foo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: B2A4A0CE1260CE33BB9663E7C4F4D0A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /home.html at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:176) - Checking match of request : '/home.html'; against '/api/**'

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:176) - Checking match of request : '/home.html'; against 'login*'

(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:219) - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /home.html; Attributes: [authenticated]

(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:348) - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d823b1ed: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@677d9ddb: Username: bar@foo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: B2A4A0CE1260CE33BB9663E7C4F4D0A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN

(AffirmativeBased.java:66) - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4098e795, returned: 1

(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:243) - Authorization successful

(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:256) - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object

(FilterChainProxy.java:313) - /home.html reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain

(HstsHeaderWriter.java:129) - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@682780f8

(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) - Chain processed normally

(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:119) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /login at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /login at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'

(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:210) - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d823b1ed: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d823b1ed: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@677d9ddb: Username: bar@foo.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: B2A4A0CE1260CE33BB9663E7C4F4D0A2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /login at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /login at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:176) - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:65) - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'

(OrRequestMatcher.java:72) - No matches found

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /login at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'

(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:156) - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login'

(FilterChainProxy.java:328) - /login at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'

(HstsHeaderWriter.java:129) - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@682780f8

(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:119) - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not configured your application that home.html is accessable for authenticated users. So you have to add something like this (i am only familiar with xml based configuration):

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home.html").fullyAuthenticated();
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions